# Can I not redirect page to client side after send?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to redirect page when i send a data from oAuth , however, I can not reach to client side by invoke `res.redirect` so i tried to put it on anywhere but it still doesn't work  .

and i got error like :
`Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

How can I change the url with `redirect`??
if it can't what is another alternative ??

Thank you in advance !

Here is the code :

```js
app.get("/callback", cors(), (req, res) => {
 

  if (req.query.code !== null && req.query.code !== undefined) {
    var token_url = "https://www.oauthserver/oauth2.0/token"; //this is Oauth server
    var options = {
      url: token_url,
      method: "POST",
      form: {
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        client_id: client_id,
        client_secret: client_secret,
        redirect_uri: redirectURI,
        code: req.query.code,
        state: req.query.state,
      },
    };

 

    request(options, function (error1, response1, body1) {
      if (!error1 && response1.statusCode == 200) {
        var tdata = JSON.parse(body1);
        var options2 = {
          url: "https://www.oauthserver/oauth2.0/resource", //this is Oauth server
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + tdata.access_token,
          },
        };
        request(options2, function (error2, response2, body2) {
          if (!error2 && response2.statusCode == 200) {
            res.redirect("http://localhost:3000"); //client Side
            res.status(200).send(body2);
          
            console.log(JSON.parse(body2));
          
          } else {
            res.status(response2.statusCode).end();
            console.log("error2 = " + response2.statusCode);
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.status(response1.statusCode).end();
        console.log("error1 = " + response1.statusCode);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: As a javascript request, returning a redirect in the headers wouldn't work as expected anyway. Do your redirect in javascript, in the response handling code.

Comment: Thank you so much then I should send the data to client and as soon as get the data in client side i should change the url  ?  what i understand is right??

Comment: That sounds right. Before you do the redirect, you might need to do something with the returned token so that it persists after the redirect.

Comment: Omg, Thank you so much for such a wisdom answering !! it helped me a lot honestly !